# Amazon API Gateway - Delete API keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Can you delete your API keys already created via AWS Management Console's Amazon API Gateway page? Perhaps we can only turn on-off 'Enabled' checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this now. If you navigate to the Amazon API Gateway page in the AWS console, click on `API Keys` in the left side panel, then you can click on the key you want to delete and press the `Delete API Key` button in the upper right hand side of the page.

Answer (score 12):

With the official aws python client you can do

```
aws apigateway delete-api-key --api-key "MyLoOnGGaNDdObScuEddDKeYYy"
```

Comment: Second that this should be updated to the correct answer.  You can easily install the official python client with 'sudo pip install boto3' then simply run this command

Comment: Currently, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

For the time being you have to use the [Amazon API Gateway REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/) to delete an API key.

Here is a way with Node.js:

- Install [aws4](https://github.com/mhart/aws4) package

  ```
  npm install aws4
  ```
- Use the `apikey:delete` [link relation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-delete/) to delete the API key:

  ```js
  var https = require('https'),           
      aws4  = require('aws4');

  https.request(aws4.sign({
    host  : 'apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    method: 'DELETE',
    path  : '/apikeys/<BASE64-API-KEY-VALUE>'
  }, {
    accessKeyId    : '<YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID>',
    secretAccessKey: '<YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY>'
  }), function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
  }).end();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The API for the API Gateway supports deleting API keys but I don't see a way to delete them via the AWS Web Console.  You can uncheck the `Enabled` box to disable them.

Comment: Thanks! I found a doc of [REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/api-key/). It seems that there is no [AWS-CLI command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/) for Amazon API Gateway yet.

Comment: API Gateway is not yet supported in any of the SDK's.  I'm sure they are working on it but its very different from other AWS API's.

Comment: I'd wait until `API Gateway` is supported in `CloudFormation` and then it may become very easy to manipulate lists of API keys.

Comment: Well, it won't be supported in CloudFormation until it is supported in the AWS SDK's.